# Making a search query using bs4 and urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

How can I make a search query using bs4 and urllib which find a search field and puts the value to fields and press submit (another url having token).

I have tried this but this didn't seem to even login.

```
import bs4 as bs
from urllib import request
from urllib import parse

# print(soup.text)

values ={'username': '1234567890',
               'password': 'mypassw'}

post_arg = parse.urlencode(values).encode('utf-8')

url = 'http://site24.way2sms.com/content/index.html?'

sauce = request.urlopen(url, post_arg)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, "lxml")
#print(sauce)


for i in soup.find_all('input', attrs={'id':'username'}):
  print(i)

#put values to input fields
#grab token, I can't find any csrf token.
#visit the desired webpage
```

Comment: The form gets submited to `http://site24.way2sms.com/Login1.action`

Comment: @t.m.adam but I want it to be submitted at     http://site24.way2sms.com/main.action?Token=4D6F18D8D010F9455BE4C0441D120E2C.w803&section=s the token is changing with each login try

Comment: No, what i mean is that you're posting your data to the wrong url, you should use the url in my previous comment. Also may have to use  `CookieJar` for your cookies.